# How to deserialize list with dynamic number of keys with same value structure?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to find an optimal way to deserialize dynamic fields that all contain the same value object structure:

```
"data": {
    "lastUpdate": 1605299294253,
    "tableData": [
        {
            "recordId": 1,
            "isSelected": 1,
            "myKey1": {
                "valueRef": 72,
                "value": "Some value"
            },
            "myKey2": {
                "valueRef": 0,
                "value": "123"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

For the tableData JSON array, I have tried this approach without success:

```
import lombok.Data;
import java.util.Map;

@Data
public class TableRowDataVO {
    private Integer recordId;
    private Integer recordStatus;
    private Map<String, TableRowDetailVO> columnData1;
    private Map<String, TableRowDetailVO> columnData2;
}
```

This class is nested into another class to encompass the entire JSON body in `data`:

```
public class TabularDataDTO {
    private Long lastUpdate;
    private List<TableRowDataVO> tableData;
}
```

and each dynamic field holds the same Object of the following type:

```
public class TableRowDetailVO {
    private Integer valueRef;
    private String value;
}
```

There is also no guarantee that there are only 2 dynamic keys. It can be 0 to many dynamic keys that are in `TableRowDataVO`, but if there are limitations that require me to settle with 2, I can do that, but if 0 to many dynamic fields are possible, that would be great. I am trying to use the ObjectMapper with TypeReference as `TabularDataVO` but it throws an exception. What is the proper way to design my objects such that `TabularDataVO` can be deserialized by the mapper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since the key is dynamic so when you process data you need some special process.

```
@Data
public class NewDTO {
    private Long lastUpdate;
    private List<Map<String, Object>> tableData;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This approach works, although it impacts the way in which object mapper maps the static keys to the map rather than field variables, but that's a tradeoff worth making in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Just to understand your question correctly. You Json is like following: -

```
"data": {
    "lastUpdate": 1605299294253,
    "tableData": [
        {
            "recordId": 1,
            "isSelected": 1,
            "myKey1": {
                "valueRef": 72,
                "value": "Some value"
            },
            "myKey2": {
                "valueRef": 0,
                "value": "123"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Not like

```
"data": {
    "lastUpdate": 1605299294253,
    "tableData": [
        {
            "recordId": 1,
            "isSelected": 1,
            "keys": [
                 {
                   "valueRef": 72,
                   "value": "Some value"
                },
                {
                  "valueRef": 0,
                  "value": "123"
               }
           ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Latter can be easily deserialized using jackson library and defining keys as List<Map<String, Object>>

Comment: Yes this how I’m receiving data from another API. If I could modify it to latter I would